# How to change array elements with their values through JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a simple array like this.

```
var array = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];
```

And I have a variable called "calc" content this simple calculation.

```
var calc = array[0] + (array[1] * array[2] + array[3] ) / array[4];
```

What I want to do is changing the array elements in the variable by their values to become the variable in this way.

```
var calc = 1 + (2 * 3 + 4 ) / 5;
```

The first thing i do is getting the elements from the array by this code, but i have no idea to how i can change the elements by their values.

```
for ( i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
   document.write( 'The ' + i + ' value is ( ' + array[i] + ' ).<br />' );
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: `array[i] = Number(array[i])` or `array = array.map(Number)` may work for you

Comment: "What I want to do is changing the array elements in the variable by their values to become the variable in this way." -- *What?*

Comment: @DaggNabbit I want to change `array[0]` with `1` and `array[1]` with `2` etc...

Comment: But `array[0]` *is* `1`. Well, it's `"1"`. Are you trying to figure out how to change `"1"` to `1`? This question is very confusing.

Comment: When you do `array[0]`, you *are* changing `array[0]` with `1`.  Were you hoping to use the *index* without needing to use `array[]`? Or were you hoping to use identifiers as pointers to specific indices in the Array? Either way, it can't be done.

Comment: @cookiemonster monster Shortly I want to decrypt that file [link](http://blogger-wp.com/encrypted%20js%20file.txt)

Comment: I don't understand what that has to do with your question.,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. If you mean how do you change the elements themselves then you can do so by this:

```
array[some index] = <the new value>;
```

Or are you asking for something like how to a way of storing the equation itself?

Comment: I don't want to change the elements in the array.I want to change
`array[0]` with `1` and `array[1]` with `2` etc... in the `calc` vaiable.

Comment: When you say array[0] you are getting 1. In this case, however, you are getting "1" represented as a string which won't work. Change your array definition to use integers instead of strings and it should be fine.

Comment: Shortly I want to decrypt that file [link](http://blogger-wp.com/encrypted%20js%20file.txt)

Comment: Your problem would be most easily solved with regular expressions I think. You could create a pattern to find every instance that the variable \_S8x15_ is used, and then replace it manually. The expression would be something like "\_S8x15_\\[([0-9]+)\\]". Then it's just a matter of replacing every instance with the value that it corresponds to in the _S8x15_ array.